# How to separate routes to specific file

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am trying separate routes to specific file in react-router-dom. when i try to console.log(routes); component is coming as undefined

routes.js:-

```
import { App } from "./components/app";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export const routes = [
    {
      component: App,
      path: '/',
    }
  ];
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { routes } from "./routes";
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);
debugger;
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router routes={routes}>
      <div>
        <Switch>

        {routes.map(props => <Route {...props} />)}

        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Comment: have you tried using `render` prop on `Route` component instead of `component`?

Comment: i didn't how it makes difference?

Comment: Nope, I was mislead. Sorry, I gave an answer that should solve the `undefined` problem.

Comment: [{component: undefined, path: "/"}] this is the value of props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you are exporting your `App` component as `default`, however you are importing using

```
import { App } from "./components/app";
```

You should change (in `routes.js`) it to:

```
import App from "./components/app";
```

You were using a named import.